# Adding Views dynamically to a horizontal linearLayout inside a scrollView makes them smaller

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to dynamically add linearLayout views based on a certain layout to the parent linearLayout "cardContainer" located in a scrollView. While the views are added and their content is fine, for some reason every card other than the first one is a bit smaller in width.

The parent linearLayout in its' parent scrollView

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svLibrary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etSearch"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The layout I am trying to add as a view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/card_tvIndex"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Index"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="14" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_tvTitle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.CardTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Title of a song" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_tvArtist"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.CardArtist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Artist Name" />
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/card_tvDuration"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="3:21"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Java code

```
void addInfoToCard() {
    TextView index = layout.findViewById(R.id.card_tvIndex);
    TextView title = layout.findViewById(R.id.card_tvTitle);
    TextView artist = layout.findViewById(R.id.card_tvArtist);
    TextView duration = layout.findViewById(R.id.card_tvDuration);
    index.setText("" + (this.index+1));
    title.setText(this.name);
    artist.setText(this.artist);
    duration.setText(AudioFile.formatDuration(this.length));
}
void displayCards(String filter) {
    if (filter.isEmpty()) {
        for (AudioCard card : list) {
            if(card.layout==null) return;
            cardContainer.addView(card.layout);
        }
    }
}
for (AudioCard card : list) {
        card.layout = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.audiocard, null);
        card.addInfoToCard();
    }
    displayCards("");
```

Comment: Did you consider using a RecyclerView or a ListView(for smaller list size)? It is built to handle such use cases.

Comment: Is there any good reason that why you don't do that in xml file?